# I cannot apply the CSS property "scroll-behaviour:smooth" when I use the property "scrollTop" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

first of all, sorry if I have a spelling or grammar error. I'm from Argentina.

I want a smooth scroll when I click on a link that carry me to the contact section (id=contact) or to the client section (id=client). But also I use a code to make an automatic loop which interferes with the smooth scroll.

```
 <body>
  <header>
    <section class="header_menu-container">
      <div class="title-container">
        <img src="images/logo_chico.jpg" alt="Bl Consultores">
        <h1>BL CONSULTORES</h1>
      </div>
      <span class="toggle-nav"></span>
      
        <div id="menu" class="menu-container">
          <div class="title-menu_container">
            <h3>MENU</h3>
            <span id="close-button"></span>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#client" class="scroll">Nuestros Clientes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contacto</a></li>
              <li><a href="servicios.html">Dpto. Productos</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Prefectura Naval</a></li>
              <li><a href="bases/ingreso.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Consulta de Expedientes</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="header-title_container">
        <h2>El mejor servicio de consultoría</h2>
        <a href="#contact">Contáctanos</a>
      </div>
    
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="who-section">
      <div>
        <h3>¿Cuál es nuestro trabajo?</h3>
        <p>Nuestro trabajo profesional incluye áreas de la Propiedad Intelectual y aquellos temas relacionados con Comercialización de Productos e inscripciones, importaciones y exportaciones, especializándonos en el area de alimentos.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="images/businessman-examining-papers-at-table.jpg" alt="Consultora" >
      </div>
   <section id="client" class="client-section">
      <h3>Tenemos la confianza de nuestros clientes</h3>
   </section>
    <section id="trying">
      <h3>Te mantenemos informado</h3>
      <div id="contain">
        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>07/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2997/12 </h2>
        
        </div>
        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>06/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 3038/12</h4>
       
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>05/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 3097/12</h4>
         
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>04/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2999/12 </h4>
        
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>04/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2998/12</h4>
         
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>01/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2993/12</h4>
       
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>29/05/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2897/12</h4>
       
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>Disposición 1207/2012-ANMAT - Prohibe la fabricación de mamaderas que contengan BISFENOL A</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>18/10/11 - Resolución 735/11-SENASA - PRODUCTOS ALIMENTICIOS - Aprueba Reglamento Técnico sobre Identidad y Calidad de Pimentón</h4>
       
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  <section id="contact" class="contact-section">
  </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

here is the css code

```
   html{
    font-size:62.5%;
    font-family: 'DM Sans',sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
   }
    #trying{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background:var(--lightest-secondary-color)
    }

    #trying h3{
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 600;
     color: var(--dark-1-primary-color);
   }
#contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 5px solid var(--darkest-secondary-color);
  }

  #contain::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display:none;
  }


  #scroll-text {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    background: var(--light-1-secondary-color);
    color: var(--dark-3-primary-color);
  }

    #scroll-text h4{
    margin: 10px 0;
     }
  
    #link{
      margin-top: 5px;
      display:block;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      color:var(--lightest-secondary-color);
     }
     #link:hover{
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  
  #scroll-text:nth-child(odd){
      background: var(--dark-1-primary-color);
      color: var(--light-1-secondary-color);
  }
```

And this is the javascript code with jquery that I use to make the scroll loop, which shows the text blocks div (id ="scroll-text")while they are going down

```
  var time;
  const contain = $("#contain");
  const scroll_text = $("#scroll-text");
    $(document).ready(function(){
      append_clone();
      pageScroll();

      contain.mouseover(function() {
        clearTimeout(time);
          }).mouseout(function() {
        pageScroll();
          });

    });

  function append_clone(){
  scroll_text.each(function(){
  
  scroll_text.clone().appendTo(contain);
});
}

function pageScroll() {
var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");

      objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 2;
 
  time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 100);
}
```

the code line that produce the error is `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 2;`

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Your HTML is not complete, and please use snippet (CTRL+M) to post the code.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are testing this on Safari it won't work as it is not supported, but in other major browsers it is, i.e. Edge Chromium, Chrome, Mozilla

Comment: Where is your `id="contain"` element? And what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I have tried it on Chrome. ANd the problem is that the smooth effect is not apllied when i click on a link of the nav that carry me to the client or the contact section